# CSS Custom border using content property

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im hoping to create a custom border something like the below image using the CSS [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property:

[image]

Is this possible?

Snippet below for where I got to

```css
.box
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.customBorder
{
  content: 'X';
  border: 10px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="customBorder box">
  Custom Border Test
</div>
```

I'm also open to jQuery answers.

Comment: You could accomplish this with CSS3 border-image, but I doubt it's possible with the content property.

Comment: The content CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. The way you are doing here is not going to work. As @RobertWade suggested, you should take a look into border-image property. Check out this w3school [article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the `content` in the border. The solution is to use `border-image` to create a custom border

```css
#borderimg1 { 
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 round;
}
```

```html
<p id="borderimg1"> create the border.</p>
```